# How to Organize, build and ship NodeJS applications specific to different customers

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, aurelia

We are building an Aurelia application.  We have common login page and home page for our customers.  But each customer will have their special customer page, which is very specif to them.  These cusomer specific pages should only be visible to the customer and not visible to others.  I need to find a proper way to to create a sub folder in my project for each customer to have their specific resources.  Even when we bundle the applicaiton for a specific customer, we should export only their own resources.

Comment: This is a very broad question that depends on too many variables. What customers, On what conditions? What do you mean "specific sub-modules?" What server-side technology? Do you want to like restrict access to a certain URL or asset, or bundle specific files beforehand? How different are their needs? It's like asking "Is it possible to explore a jungle?" Short answer : yes, it is possible. Long answer : it's off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Read environment variable to get path to a module to load.  Use `require(pathToModuleToLoad)` to load it and let it do its thing.  Not sure what else you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using dynamic routing. There have been a few folks asking this question publicly. One example is here https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/dynamicaly-load-routes/1906

Note that Aurelia also works with remote view, as an example is here https://codesandbox.io/s/8ljmrq3vql

One common things about ultra dynamic scenarios is you need a proper dynamic script loader (requirejs, systemjs, fuseboxjs), not bundler (webpack).